# checking preg_replace content

Tags: php, preg-replace

i want to check if the content in preg_replace function is less than 25 characters or not.

```
$i= preg_replace("'\< (.*)\>'Ui","< <a href=\"x.php?q=\\1\">\\1</a>>",$i);
```

if yes,

```
<a href="x.php?q=hello">hello</a> > // a link to x.php?q=hello
```

if no,

```
< hello >
```

how can i check it? thanks. (and i'd thank you if you can recommend an online source for preg_replace function)

Answer (score 0):

By replacing .* with .{0,25} you can limit the length matched to 25. This will leave longer strings untouched. If you want the replacement to depend on the length, either replace twice with different patterns or use preg_replace_callback.